# How to update records in a multiindex dataframe with a single index one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, multi-index

I need to update a multi-index dataframe with a single-index one. The new dataframe is a subset of the old one, just with new values, so no new column or row creation. Only the selected slice(s) are updated, and this needs to support updating more than one column at once. I'd like pandas to do the row index parsing automatically and only overwrite the rows supplied.

Can this be done in an API-native way in pandas 0.24.2 without loops, custom functions, resetting index, or creating multi-index? (What's the point of having a multi-index if you cannot slice and update?) I've searched through other questions and have found no up-to-date answer that applies to this particular use case or offers an elegant solution.

Here's some code.

```py
df_old = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 'x', 0, 0, 0], ['a', 'y', 0, 0, 0], ['a', 'z', 0, 0, 0],
     ['b', 'x', 0, 0, 0], ['b', 'y', 0, 0, 0], ['b', 'z', 0, 0, 0],
    ],
    columns=['i1', 'i2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])

df_new = pd.DataFrame([['x', 1, 2], ['y', 3, 4]],
                      columns=['i2', 'c1', 'c2']).set_index('i2')

df_old 
Out[]:
       c1  c2  c3
i1 i2            
a  x    0   0   0
   y    0   0   0
   z    0   0   0
b  x    0   0   0
   y    0   0   0
   z    0   0   0

df_new
Out[]: 
    c1  c2
i2        
x    1   2
y    3   4
```

Ideally, I'd like the following one-line command to work but it does absolutely nothing. Not even any warning pops out. I've also tried merge and join to no avail.

```
df_old.loc[idx['a'], :].update(df_new)
```

The expected result looks like the following where only the selected 'a' slice is updated.

```
       c1  c2  c3
i1 i2            
a  x    1   2   0
   y    3   4   0
   z    0   0   0
b  x    0   0   0
   y    0   0   0
   z    0   0   0
```

[dataframe summary in one clear picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTLxk.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Calling `loc` on update won't work because `loc` returns a copy.

Comment: @cs95 but when you set numerical values it does modify the original df (something like ```df_old.loc[idx['a', :]]=-1```)

Comment: Yes, because you're performing an assignment... the semantics are different. See the difference between `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in python.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me if (1) every index in `df_new` have a corresponding index in `df_old`; 
(2) the ordering of `i2` indices are the same in `df_old` and `df_new`. The second constraint is needed because the order of elements of the left-hand slice follows the order in `df_old` rather than `df_new.index`. I'm not sure whether that is a bug or an intended behaviour.

```
df_old.loc[('a', df_new.index), df_new.columns] = df_new.values
```

More information on MultiIndex slicing can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers).

Comment: Thanks. There's no guarantee in my data that the ordering is the same. But this could work with an extra step or sorting both dataframes on the same index.

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by [GZ0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157759/gz0) is by far one of the few that actually worked for updating a portion of a data frame with multiindex.  But it was painfully slow for my scenario (took 9s for each 800 data points).  The slowness is primarily because we are looking up the indices to write to.

My solution below is an extension to [GZ0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157759/gz0)'s solution to solve my specific scenario and it runs about 110ms for each cat (roughly 800 data points).  This solution just overwrites the whole series by following the subcat's original ordering from df instead of matching up individual indices.  May not be a suitable solution for everyone.

**scenario:**
I have only two levels of row indices (cat, subcat) and running a rolling timeseries calculation on a field (input_field_col) for all of subcats, cat by cat.  Results of this timeseries calc creates a new data series column in the original data frame.

```
ds = df.loc[cat,input_field_col].rolling(winlen).mean()
df.loc[cat,new_col] = ds.values
```